# Can `tcpdump ether host` filter with a mask to get, for example, hosts with a specific OUI?

Tags: wifi, ethernet, tcpdump, wireshark, pcap

I'm trying to filter traffic by `src ether host` to see all devices with a specific MAC prefix.  If this were like IP, it might filter with `src ether host aa:bb:cc:00:00:00/24` to see OUI's matching `aa:bb:cc`...but it doesn't like that.

**Is there a way to match by MAC prefix or mask?**

In case it matters:

This is for Wi-Fi, so technically it's an SA address that you can see if you scroll to the right (`tcpdump` puts that in the `src ether host` field).

```
13:12:48.139316 1.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11b -41dBm signal -41dBm signal antenna 0 0us BSSID:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff DA:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff SA:aa:bb:cc:84:05:7c Probe Request (emporia) [5.5* 11.0* 1.0* 2.0* 6.0 12.0 24.0 48.0 Mbit]
```

Comment: Maybe this gets you started: `tcpdump "ether[6:2] == 0xabcd and ether[8:1] == 0xef`. I didn't figure out how to get only packets originating from that host, tho. Source: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086766/how-to-filter-mac-addresses-using-tcpdump)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names (host, src host, ether, ether src,...) are basically shortcuts to specific bytes in the corresponding tcp od ip packets.
There are no wildcards allowed in tcpdump-filters, so one has to dig deeper into the tcp-packets themselves.
The ethernet src-address is in the 6 bytes starting at ether[6], the ethernet dest-address is in the 6 bytes starting at ether[0].

So if one wants to filter for three bytes of the src-address, one has to filter for the bytes 6,7 and 8. Since one can't filter for tree bytes (`"tcpdump: data size must be 1, 2, or 4"`) the filter has to be broken into two parts.
bytes 6 and 7: ether[6:2], byte 8: ether[8:1]

Which means, the filter would look like:
`ether[6:2]==0xaabb and ether[8:1]==0xcc`